# How to set a the role type text in the .Net Role Provider?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5, role-manager

In my `UserController.Login` action, I am trying to `AddUserToRole()` for an authenticated user, with the value of one of the user entity's `MembershipType.MembershipName` navigation property:

```
Roles.AddUserToRole(thisUser.UserName, thisUser.MembershipType.MembershipName);
```

I'm not using the bloated auto-generated membership types and simply want to add the text value to the user's role - not a range of roles.  User --> one role.

In trying to figure this out, I defined a custom role provider in web.config:

```
<roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="CustomRoleProvider">
  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add name="CustomRoleProvider" 
       type="MyWebsite.CustomRoleProvider, 
             CustomMembershipEF, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral" 
       connectionStringName="MyDbContext"
       enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" 
       requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" writeExceptionsToEventLog="false" />
  </providers>
</roleManager>
```

So calling Roles.AddUserToRole() calls the method in my custom provider, but I'm not sure what to do in that method.

Earlier I simply added `enabled="true"` to the `rolemanager` section in web.config, but was getting the following error:

> Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider.  It may not
>   be installed.

Here's my custom role provider (although I don't know why I should need this, as I just want to add the role name):

```
public class CustomRoleProvider : RoleProvider
{
    public override bool IsUserInRole(string username, string roleName)
    {
        using (var db = new MyApp.DAL.MyAppDbContext())
        {
            var user = db.Users.SingleOrDefault(u => u.UserName == username);
            if (user == null)
                return false;

            if (user.MembershipType != null && user.MembershipType.MembershipName == roleName)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public override string[] GetRolesForUser(string username)
    {
        using (var db = new MyApp.DAL.MyAppDbContext())
        {
            var user = db.Users.SingleOrDefault(u => u.UserName == username);
            if (user == null)
                return new string[] { };

            return db.MembershipTypes == null ? new string[] { } :
              db.MembershipTypes.Select(u => u.MembershipName).ToArray();
        }
    }

    // -- Snip --

    public override string[] GetAllRoles()
    {
        using (var db = new MyApp.DAL.MyAppDbContext())
        {
            return db.MembershipTypes.Select(r => r.MembershipName).ToArray();
        }
    }

    // -- Snip --

    public override void AddUsersToRoles(string[] usernames, string[] roleNames)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
```

I'm thinking this should be quite simple to accomplish - simply set the user's role name... assistance appreciated.

**-- Update --**

I commented out the content of the custom `AddUserToRole()` method, and the user is able to login.  However, in calling an action method, the role check wasn't performed - ie. should have failed since the role name doesn't actually exist:

```
    [HttpGet]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [Authorize(Roles="WaitConfirmationxxx")]
    public ActionResult WaitConfirmation()
    {
```

I also noticed that `IsInRole()` called the custom `GetRolesForUser()` method which does a db call in it.  Not exactly optimal, and wondering if this is actually how it should be?

```
                if(User.IsInRole("WaitConfirmation"))
                {
                    // email address has not yet been confirmed
                    return RedirectToAction("WaitConfirmation", "User");
                }
```

-- Update --

My mistake here was thinking that I needed to use `Roles.AddUserToRole()`  (unless someone comments otherwise).

I also added the `cacheRolesInCookie` parameter in the `roleManager` definition in the web.config:

```
<roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="CustomRoleProvider" cacheRolesInCookie="true">
```

So now when I call  `if(User.IsInRole("WaitConfirmation"))`, my custom `GetRolesForUser(string username)` is called.

The problem now is that none of the `Authorization` attributes work.  Suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove the `[AllowAnonymous]` attribute, change it to this:

```
[HttpGet]
[Authorize(Roles="WaitConfirmationxxx")]
public ActionResult WaitConfirmation()
{
```

If your RoleProvider is configured correctly, it should kick into this method when it tries to authorise from the attribute on the above method.

```
public override string[] GetRolesForUser(string username)
        {
```

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that. Just tested and it all seems to be working.